# Como obter a Url atual em um WebView - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

Estou tentando obter a URL atual pois quando estiver em determinada URL preciso abrir a camera do celular. Com android consegui, mais com iOS no Xcode não estou conseguindo, tentei esse código mais sem sucesso

```c
- (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest *) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigationType {
    NSString  *URL = request.URL.absoluteString;    NSLog(@"%@",URL);
    NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];


    return [self shouldStartDecidePolicy: request];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de colocar uma WebKit View no StoryBoard e arrastar o Outlet para o código utilize o seguinte código:

ViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <WKNavigationDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```c
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    //URL do site que deseja iniciar  webView
    NSString * mURL = @"https://www.google.com.br";
    NSString * webStringURL = [mURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_webView loadRequest: requestObj];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {

    if(navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
        // Aqui você recebe a URL atual
        NSLog(@"%@", navigationAction.request.URL);
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}

@end
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta